# INDEX and MATCH function working on range but not on table reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using the below formula with range, getting desired value

=INDEX(A2:A22,MATCH("worksplendid.com",A2:A21,0))

[image]

But by referencing the table table_, unable to get the value:

=INDEX(table_,MATCH("worksplendid.com",A2:A21,0))

[image]

Comment: If you refer the Table, it will return the table...

Answer (score 1):

In the first formula you are using a single column array, so INDEX is expecting only a single index. In the second formula you are using the whole 2D table. INDEX is expecting a row and column index.

Try `INDEX(table_[Listing]...` or adding a column index `INDEX(... ,1)`.

Comment: Unable to follow:  Try INDEX(table_[Listing]... or adding a column index INDEX(... ,1).  Does it mean not using MATCH? Could you please provide the exact formula?

Comment: Just use "table_[Listing]" (i.e. only the column) in your original formula instead of just "table_" (the whole table).